# How to fix "ld: warning: ignoring file: file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked?"

Tags: macos, go, macos-mojave

I tried "go install" after update my MacOS to "Mojave".

Unexpectedly I got following error: ld: warning: ignoring file

/var/folders/8q/7w329nzx6h1ck5gn44gvksg80000gn/T/go-link-040352046/000000.o, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0x4C 0x01 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0xC7 0x02 0x00 0x00 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00 ) which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /var/folders/8q/7w329nzx6h1ck5gn44gvksg80000gn/T/go-link-040352046/000000.o

I appreciate your help. I cannot find where var/folders located.

Thanks

Comment: The full path is given in the error. `/var/folders/` is at the root of your filesystem (as indicated by the leading slash).

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove file `resource.syso` from the current project directory. File has a wrong signature.

Comment: Please include more details and explain how / why this addresses the question.

Comment: please add this information inside the answer, instead of in a comment, so it's more useful to others who may overlook the comment section